# Spring boot JSON response

Tags: json, spring-boot

Here's my code

```
@RequestMapping("/bookList") 
public List<Books> list() {
    return bookService.booksList();
}

public class Books {
   private String author;
   private String isbn;
   private String title;
}
```

#### Current response

`[["TOM",123456,"ABC"],["JANE",789000,"CDE"]]`

#### Expected response

```
"Books": [
    {"author": "TOM", "isbn": "123456", "title": "ABC"},
    {"author": "JANE", "isbn": "789000", "title": "CDE"}
]
```

What is the code change I need to make?

Answer (score 0):

Your `List<Books>` is correctly returned as JSON. Your option would be to wrap it into another object:

```
public class BookList {
    public List<Books> books;
}
```

and return a `BookList`instead of `List<Books>`.

But to be honest, I would not recommend you do do that. It's not very restful.

Comment: Please follow the guidelines of asking questions and edit your question or create a new one if its a new topic and take a look at formatting questions & code.

Answer (score 0):

session.createQuery returns Object[]. I used Criteria query with projections inside my DAOIMPL class and I got the expected output.